# Trying to get JSON from PHP file with js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to fetch data from my Wordpress server, where I have a php file that returns some data. I'm trying to use it as api.

I'm fetching with the old *fetch()* function in React JS from localhost.

JS Part

```
fetch(url, option)
      .then((res) => {
        try {
          if (res.ok) {
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
          } else {
            throw new Error(res);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      })
      .then((resJson) => {
        return resJson.data;
      });
    //.catch((err) => console.log(err));


// calling the function in other file

getData('http://My_URL.com/data-tb/api.php?sId=566.b.a23w&locationId=1', {
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         Accept: "application/json",
      }})
```

PHP File

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

//---------------------------------------------------
//get customer data
if( !empty($_GET))
{
    $data =array(); 
    $sec_id = $_GET['sId'];
    $locationId = $_GET['locationId'];
    if($sec_id == $secret_id)
    {
          $query="SELECT * from customer where location_id ='".$locationId."' AND result IS NULL ORDER BY id DESC";
          $exec=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
          if(mysqli_num_rows($exec)>0){
            $row= mysqli_fetch_all($exec, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $data['data'] = $row;  
            $data['status'] = "success";
                
          }else{
            $data['status'] = "fail";
            $data['error'] = "Data Not Found";
          }
    }else{
        $data['status'] = "fail";
        $data['error'] = "Request Not Verified.";
        
    }
    
    
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I'm expecting a JSON response but instead I get:

Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://My_URL.com/data-tb/api.php?sId=566.b.a23w&locationId=1', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://My_URL.com/data-tb/api.php?sId=A566.b.a23w&locationId=1"
[[Prototype]]: Response

And an error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 176

**I understand that my request doesn't return a JSON but if I try Postman or if I just type the url on Chrome I get this result:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "13",
            "first_name": "test1",
            "last_name": "test2",
            "birthday": "2021",
            "street": "st no 23",
            "nr": "234",
            "zip": "6100",
            "location_id": "1",
            "result": null
        }
    ],
    "status": "success"
}{
    "status": "fail",
    "error": "Request Not Verified."
}
```

Comment: You can use res.json() on the thing you return from the API, because those are two JSON object joined together. You have result and then an error. I'm not expert in Wordpress but if you don't have `"Request Not Verified"` in your code, it mean that it's from Wordpress and you're not using it correctly.

Comment: When you echo the json, make sure to exit, too

Comment: Thx, both answer helps me out :)